# How to update nested resources Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have models - Test, Question, and TeacherAnswers.

*test.rb*

```
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions
end
```

*question.rb*

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :test
  has_many :teacher_answers, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :teacher_answers
end
```

*teacher_answer.rb*

```
class TeacherAnswer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
end
```

and controllers
*test_controller.rb*

```
---    
standard scaffold code
---
def test_params
      params.require(:test).permit(:title, 
                                    questions_attributes: [:question_text, :test_id, teacher_answers_attributes: [:teacher_answer_text, :correct, :question_id]],)
    end
```

question_controller.rb

```
---    
standard scaffold code
---
def question_params
      params.require(:question).permit(:question_text, :test_id,
                                        teacher_answers_attributes: [:teacher_answer_text, :correct, :question_id])
    end
```

When creating new test with questions and answers it creates everything correctly, but when updating:

1. can't remove questions
2. when saving it doesn't update the questions and answers, but saves new ones with already old ones i.e. when updating test with 2 questions, after saving it will have 4 questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should permit `:id` and `:_destroy` in the `test_params` like below for the `update` and `delete` to work correctly.

```
def test_params
  params.require(:test).permit(:title, questions_attributes: [:id, :question_text, :test_id, :_destroy, teacher_answers_attributes: [:id, :teacher_answer_text, :correct, :question_id, :_destroy]])
end
```

***Update***

You should also add `allow_destroy: true` for `test.rb` and `question.rb`

```
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions, allow_destroy: true
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :test
  has_many :teacher_answers, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :teacher_answers, allow_destroy: true
end
```

Comment: thank you. the `:id` solved update error. how to solve deleting problem?

Comment: had to add also `allow_destroy: true` to _test.rb_ and _question.rb_

Comment: @MartinsB Yes. Good catch :)

Comment: @MartinsB Please accept the answer if it solves your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

1. accepts_nested_attributes_for by default does not allow deletion, use delete: true
2. Pass id to form, via hidden tag